# android sqlite delete rows older than x days using db.delete

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know it is possible to delete rows older than X days using

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE Date <= datetime('now','-7 day')";
db.execSQL(sql);
```

However `db.execSQL(sql)` does not return a value and I need to confirm that deletion was successful.

`db.delete()` returns an int but how to set the WhereClause and whereArgs to delete all rows older than 7 days for example?

```
String whereClause = ...
new String[] whereArgs=....
int deletedRows = db.delete("TABLE", whereClause , whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `whereArgs` variable if your condition is fixed:

```
Date <= datetime('now','-7 day')
```

So you can do it like this:

```
String whereClause = "Date <= datetime('now', '-7 day')"; 
int deletedRows = db.delete("TABLE", whereClause , null);
```

If you want to be able to pass the number of days that you want to subtract as a parameter, then you will need `whereArgs`:

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {"7"}
String whereClause = "Date <= datetime('now', '-' || ? || ' day')"; 
int deletedRows = db.delete("TABLE", whereClause, whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your final code snippet, `whereClause` is `"Date <= datetime('now','-7 day')"` and `whereArgs` is `null`:

```java
int deletedRows = db.delete("TABLE", "Date <= datetime('now','-7 day')" , null);
```